# SciChart iOS correct CategoryDateTimeLabelProvider implementation

Tags: ios, swift, scichart

I am currently building iOS app (Swift 4, Xcode 9.2) using SciChart (2.1.0.1961).

I want to use CategoryDateTimeAxis to display dates but i want to override how it display date format and always to point to specific TimeZone for example (GMT-1).

I found in SciChart documentation example how to do this but i have error like on attached image.

[image]

If someone had same or similar problem can tell how to make it work? 
I will appreciate any help.